# Is this infinite series of continuous functions $f(x)=\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} \sin(\frac{x}{n^2})$ continuous?

Tags: calculus, sequences-and-series, functions, convergence-divergence

The original question: Consider the function $$f(x)=\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} \sin\left(\frac{x}{n^2}\right).$$ Is $f$ a continuous function on $\mathbb{R}$ ?

I know that the infinite sum of continuous functions need not be continuous. But, my question is that if I know that a (general term) goes to $0$ when $n$ tends to infinity, can I say that the function $f(x)$ is continuous?

Thanks,
Dor.

Comment: $x$ is unspecified ? (you don't have $x\in [-1,1]$ ?)

Answer (score 8):

**Hint**. One may recall that
$$
|\sin u |\le |u|, \quad u \in \mathbb{R},
$$
from which one sees that the convergence is normal over any compact set $[-A,A]$ since
$$
\left|\sum_{n=1}^\infty\sin\left(\frac{x}{n^2}\right)\right|\le\sum_{n=1}^\infty\left|\sin\left(\frac{x}{n^2}\right)\right|\le\sum_{n=1}^\infty\frac{A}{n^2}<\infty, \quad x \in [-A,A], \, A>0,
$$ then the series is *uniformly* convergent over each $[-A,A]$, then the sum is continuous on $\mathbb{R}$.

Comment: Hi, first of all thank you.
 I understand you way of solving this problem but  i might forget to mention that it was a question in my exam, and  i didn't though about you way, and i solved as i describe and I'm not pretty sure its ok.

Comment: @DorShoshani You are welcome. If the general term goes to $0$, this is not enough to get continuity even if each function is continuous: $\sum_{n\ge1} \frac{x^n}n=-\log(1-x)$ is not continous at $x=1$ even if each term is continuous at $x=1$ and even if the general term tends to $0$.

Comment: but. the genteel term tends to 0 only when -1<=x<=1 , or am I miss something ?

Comment: I mean that each $(-1,1) \ni x  \mapsto \frac{x^n}n$ is coninuous on its domain, the general terms goes to $0$ on its domain, *but* the series is not continous at $1$. When there is *uniform* convergence one may  conclude.

Comment: oh. i see.so my answer for this question is not that legit ,right? :/

Comment: @Dor Shoshani No, it isn't.